# Differences between C and Python sockets

Tags: python, c, sockets

I am working in a C program with sockets. I found a proxy python script which is working with my program:

```py
import threading
import serial
import socket


def setup():
    """
    This function sets up the variables needed, including the serial port,
    and it's speed/port settings, listening socket, and localhost adddress.
    """
    global clisock, cliaddr, svrsock, ser
    # Change this to the COM port your XBee Cellular module is using.  On
    # Linux, this will be /dev/ttyUSB#
    comport = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
    # This is the default serial communication speed of the XBee Cellular
    # module
    comspeed = 9600
    buffer_size = 4096  # Default receive size in bytes
    debug_on = 0  # Enables printing of debug messages
    toval = None  # Timeout value for serial port below
    # Serial port object for XBCell modem
    ser = serial.Serial(comport,comspeed,timeout=toval)
    # Listening socket (accepts incoming connection)
    svrsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Allow address reuse on socket (eliminates some restart errors)
    svrsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    clisock = None
    cliaddr = None  # These are first defined before thread creation
    addrtuple = ('localhost', 1881)  # Address tuple for localhost
    # Binds server socket to localhost (allows client program connection)
    svrsock.bind(addrtuple)
    svrsock.listen(1)  # Allow (1) connection


def ComReaderThread():
    """
    This thread listens on the defined serial port object ('ser') for data
    from the modem, and upon receipt, sends it out to the client over the
    client socket ('clisock').
    """
    global clisock
    while (1):
        resp = ser.read()  ## Read any available data from serial port
        print("Received {} bytes from modem.".format(len(resp)))

        clisock.sendall(resp)  # Send RXd data out on client socket
        print("Sent {} byte payload out socket to client.".format(len(resp)))


def SockReaderThread():
    """
    This thread listens to the MQTT client's socket and upon receiving a
    payload, it sends this data out on the defined serial port ('ser') to the
    modem for transmission.
    """

    global clisock
    while (1):
        data = clisock.recv(4096)  # RX data from client socket
        # If the RECV call returns 0 bytes, the socket has closed
        if (len(data) == 0):
            print("ERROR - socket has closed.  Exiting socket reader thread.")
            return 1  # Exit the thread to avoid a loop of 0-byte receptions
        else:
            print("Received {} bytes from client via socket.".format(len(data)))
            print("Sending payload to modem...")
            bytes_wr = ser.write(data)  # Write payload to modem via UART/serial
            print("Wrote {} bytes to modem".format(bytes_wr))

def main():
    setup()  # Setup the serial port and socket
    global clisock, svrsock
    if (not clisock):  # Accept a connection on 'svrsock' to open 'clisock'
        print("Awaiting ACCEPT on server sock...")
        (clisock,cliaddr) = svrsock.accept()  # Accept an incoming connection
        print("Connection accepted on socket")
    # Make thread for ComReader
    comthread = threading.Thread(target=ComReaderThread)
    comthread.start()  # Start the thread
    # Make thread for SockReader
    sockthread = threading.Thread(target=SockReaderThread)
    sockthread.start()  # Start the thread

main()
```

I tried to do the same proxy script in C

```c
#include "project.h"
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int fd,baudrate=9600,sock,new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client;

int setup(){
    
    int opt=1;
    sock=0;
    if(wiringPiSetup() <0) return 1;
    if((fd=serialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate))<0) return 1;
    printf("Serial communication opened \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1881);
    
    int addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, addrlen)<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(sock, 1) <0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("1\n");
    addrlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    socklen_t sin_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((new_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sin_size)) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
    printf("Accepted new connection from a client %s:%d\n", client_ip, ntohs(client.sin_port));
    
    printf("1\n");
    return 0;
}


PI_THREAD(socketRead){
    

    int valread;
    char buffer[4096]={0}; 

    printf("hola %i\n",new_socket);
    //Nos mantenemos a la escucha
    for(;;){
        //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        //valread = recv( new_socket, buffer, 1024,0);
        while((valread = read(new_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1))>0){
        /*if ( valread < 0 ) {
            printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
            return 0 ;
        }*/
        buffer[valread]=0;  
        printf("buffer %s\n",buffer);
        write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        }
    } 
    
}

PI_THREAD(uartRead){
    

    int valread;
    char buffer[4096]={0}; 

    
    //Nos mantenemos a la escucha
    for(;;){
        //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        valread = read( fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        //valread = read(new_socket,buffer,4096);
        //send( new_socket, buffer,4096,0);
        write(new_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        printf("recibido\n");
    } 
    
}


int main(){
    
    setup();
    printf("adios %i\n",new_socket);
    /* Thread creation */
    piThreadCreate (socketRead);
    piThreadCreate (uartRead);
    for(;;){}
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have not found differences between both programs, so my question is if there are any differences between Python and C libraries. With Python I am allow to see read the messages but in C I only receive 0x10 and 0x11. So, are there any differences between libraries or is something with my C script?

Comment: Python uses the same system-provide C calls.. it’s a thin wrapper and they are effectively the same. I’ve no doubt there is a bug in the code, possibly related to porting between C and Python “in general”.

Comment: Mmm is it also the same read function? Because having the same parameters in both scripts and following the same structure I do not understand..

Comment: It works the same at the OS level, yes.  Thin wrappers to bridge the languages/binding. Work to create a minimal failing-differing case.

Comment: is the data really ASCII strings?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That' s what I think, all the data is comming from the MQTT paho library.. But, if it is working in Python, does it matter in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PI_THREAD(uartRead){
    ...
    char buffer[4096]={0};
    ... 
        valread = read( fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        ...
        write(new_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

In this code you read `valread` byte from the serial line but you always `write` 4096 byte (`sizeof(buffer)`). This means you send not only the data from the serial line but lots of junk data which are in the `buffer`.

The problem is thus not the difference between sockets in Python and C but just a bug in the C program.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have the same problem in the other thread.. I have been so much hours trying to find the bug.. Thanks!